# Following Introduction to Building Managed ODP.NET I get this error "Unrecognized configuration section oracle.manageddataaccess.client."

Tags: oracle, configuration-files, odp.net, managed

Following this tutorial, [Introduction to Building ODP.NET, Managed Driver Applications](http://www.oracle.com/webfolder/technetwork/tutorials/obe/db/12c/r1/appdev/dotnet/Web_version_Fully_Managed_ODPnet_OBE/odpnetmngdrv.html)

In the topic "Connect using the TNS_ADMIN Property", when I run I get "Unrecognized configuration section oracle.manageddataaccess.client" error.

Answer (score 5):

I ran into this issue myself in a multi-project solution including a Website. In my case, I have a "Data" project responsible for all Database interaction. It is in THIS project's `App.config` file that I needed to put my Oracle settings. In fact, the file was already prepared for me with the proper `configSections` to handle it.

Either way, this is how my App.config file looks now. Either add the missing `configSections` to your config file, or - if you have multiple projects - ensure you add the settings to the correct project's `App.config` file.

Your version numbers and PublicKeyTokens may vary.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <section name="oracle.manageddataaccess.client"
      type="OracleInternal.Common.ODPMSectionHandler, Oracle.ManagedDataAccess, Version=4.122.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89b483f429c47342"/>
  </configSections>
  <system.data>
    <DbProviderFactories>
      <remove invariant="Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client"/>
      <add name="ODP.NET, Managed Driver" invariant="Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client" description="Oracle Data Provider for .NET, Managed Driver"
        type="Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client.OracleClientFactory, Oracle.ManagedDataAccess, Version=4.122.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89b483f429c47342"/>
    </DbProviderFactories>
  </system.data>
  <runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
      <dependentAssembly>
        <publisherPolicy apply="no"/>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Oracle.ManagedDataAccess" publicKeyToken="89b483f429c47342" culture="neutral"/>
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="4.121.0.0 - 4.65535.65535.65535" newVersion="4.122.1.0"/>
      </dependentAssembly>
    </assemblyBinding>
  </runtime>
  <oracle.manageddataaccess.client>
    <version number="*">
      <settings>
        <setting name="TNS_ADMIN" value="C:\Oracle\product\11.2.0\client_1\network\admin\" />
      </settings>
    </version>
  </oracle.manageddataaccess.client>
</configuration>
```